# Many images on one page - having issues placing them

Tags: adobe-indesign

I work on my school's yearbook and I have about 15 images that I have to place on two pages, and I can't find a creative way to place them.  I can't post the images here because of security reasons; are there any templates that could be of use or any tips?

This is off topic but I could argue that only placing a few really good images could be better than placing like 10 okay ish ones...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a really difficult question to answer because the only real answer is that it should be done in a way that looks good for the purpose. This is so obvious it seems condescending.

Programmers have a term for a process that they use to help themselves find the flaws in their program logic: Rubber Ducking. Essentially, they explain out loud to a rubber duck line by line what they are doing and why and this helps to clarify problems they aren't able to see.

So what might be helpful to you is to have a dialog with yourself: what am I trying to show with these photos? Who is in them that must be shown? Do any have compelling visual interest or composition? If I scatter them on the floor is this better than if I pin them up on the wall? If I pin them up on the wall and take a photo of them, is this too hip, too hippie or too hipster? If I collage this is it too casual? If I grid it is it too suit-and-tie? If i juxtapose a photo of a cow, a pig, and the principal will I receive my diploma?

Really the point of design and art in general is to eliminate possibilities.

Comment: Wait, so Ernie on Sesame Street is a programmer? Who knew?

Comment: Its funny, I haven't seen that bit since the early 70s and I still know the words to that song.

Answer (score 0):

I agree. How you place images would depend upon how you want the pages to look like.Trying to place all of them in most attractive manner is far better than placing a few only.